# Java - Custom/standard validation with Annotations

Tags: java, validation, reflection, annotations

I'm using annotations in a project. The thing is i'm making custom validation that (partly) depends on annotations. I'm also making own annotations, but I want to use as much as I can from the JSR 303 standard.

to check if a field 'passes' the annotation constraints i've written some methods. Example:

```
static boolean isNotNullValid(Field f){
    boolean valid = true;
    if(f.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class)){
        Object o = ObjectGetter.getFieldValue(f);
        if(o==null){
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

It's quite a lot of work to do this type of validation for all annotations. Is there some method i'm missing, like .isValid() ? I mean, of course, for the standard annotations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to code that by yourself. You should instead rely on an implementation of the JSR, for example [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/docs). The [Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) it implements allows getting a set of constraint violations based on the annotations on the bean.

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for the reply. I was already affraid that I was doing too much. This helps me out a lot! Thanks!!